# Scaling Auto-complete with Rails and choosing the correct one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am giving my users the ability to find-by-autocomplete a location they type in (just like Google Maps does) but i don't know if it will respond fast enough in the long run when i have 100,000s plus locations that have been added to my database. Right now i am using [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) but it seems like i should be using something more robust.How do i know if the autocomplete gem or plugin i am using will be able to scale very well in the long run? Is this a valid consideration? Should i be looking to use a different Autocomplete method or is the above ok?

Comment: Scaling and rails in the same question? lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comfortable with Redis, I think the Soulmate gem from SeatGeek is pretty robust.

https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate

Comment: Interesting, i will take a look at it, have you used it?